# Cmake cannot find boost_python and boost_numpy

Tags: cmake, boost

I'm trying to install a software which requires Boost. So I downloaded boost by running this command

```
 wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.65.1/boost_1_65_1.tar.gz
```

and then running bootstrap and then the generated b2.

When I'm running the cmake command for the software I'm trying to install I get the following error:

```
cmake -DWITH_BOOST_STATIC=OFF -DBUILD_INTERFACE_PYTHON=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_APPS=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/installations/face_swap -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   regex
--   timer
--   thread
--   chrono
--   system
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine CXX configuration
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find SWIG (missing: SWIG_EXECUTABLE SWIG_DIR) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1947 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.1

  Boost include path: /usr/local/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_python
          boost_numpy

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  interfaces/python/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/face_swap/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/face_swap/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

It's looking in /usr/local/include but I can see I have files like libboost_python3.so at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Boost is available from the Ubuntu `universe` repository (as individual packages, or via the `libboost-all-dev` metapackage) - why are you trying to build it?